# Add class based on published state

Tags: 7, theming

I am trying to add a body class to my site in template.php based on whether or not a node is published or not. I had a look around here and on drupal.org and pieced together some code but I am getting an error. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
function responsive_process_html(&$variables) { 

 if ($node->status == 1){
        //$variables['#attributes']['class'][] = 'pub';
        $variables['classes_array'][] = 'published';
    }

    else {
        $variables['classes_array'][] = 'not-published';
    }
}
```

... but I am getting this error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: node in responsive_process_html() (line 37 of /sites/all/themes/responsive/template.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in responsive_process_html() (line 37 of /sites/all/themes/responsive/template.php).
```

I also tried `$variables['#attributes']['class'][] = 'published';` instead of `$variables['classes_array'][] = 'published';` but it made no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up finding a sweet little function from the Zen Theme (7.x-5.1). In template.php add this preprocess node function:

```
function MY_THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables, $hook) {
        // Add $unpublished variable.
        $variables\['unpublished'\] = (!$variables\['status'\]) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    }
```

Then in node.tpl.php or your node--custom.tpl.php grab the `unpublished` variable and add something like this:

```
 <?php if ($unpublished): ?>
    <!-- whatever code you want here using the variable-->
    <p class="unpublished"><?php print t('Unpublished'); ?></p>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

You can then theme this any way you want and it's a great visual indicator to the user that the node is unpublished. (see screen capture).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

in your theme's template.php:

```
function mytemplate_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $node = menu_get_object();
  if ($node && isset($node->nid)) {
    if ($node->status) {
      $vars['classes_array'][] = 'published';
    } else {
      $vars['classes_array'][] = 'unpublished';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That `$node` variable isn't defined, but may be passed along inside...

```
$node=$variables['node'];

if (!empty($node)) { // we are displaying a node

  if ($node->status) {
    // we are published
  } else {
    // we aren't published
  }

} else { // we are in a view or another none node type page
  // do whatever here then
}
```

... if you are displaying a full node page, so I'd check to see if it's in there.  It would be in preprocess_page() so may be available to preprocess_html() as well.

ADDITION:

For example, see if this works....

```
function YOURTHEME_OR_MODULE_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

  $node=$variables['node'];

  if (!empty($node)) {

    if ($node->status) {
      $variables['classes'].=' published';
    } else {
      $variables['classes'].=' not-published';
    }

  }

}
```

...but I am just looking at the code as I don't have a D7 testbed to actually run this on.

Comment: I tried this and with `preprocess_page` and though I no longer get any errors, the code does not seem to do anything. I don't see a body class added to a node either way.

Comment: what I was saying is `$node` is certainly not declared, but rather may be passed within the `$variables` array argument.  In D7, `preprocess_html()` is definitely where you want to be trying this.  I just do not know precisely what variable you need to modify.  A quick look at `html.tpl.php` in the system module's directory suggests `$variables['classes']` is a string of classes that you might be able to append to IF the node object is also passed along to this.

Comment: I tried the new code and variations of it but still no joy. I did find a nice alternate solution that works below based on code from the newest version of the Zen Theme.