# Drupal add class to body if page is unpublished

Tags: theming

I would like to be able to add an unpublished class to the body tag of a node (for both its main view and edit view) if the node has been unpublished.

How can I do this?

---

**Steps I have taken:**

1) Node Object
The [node object](https://drupal.org/node/49768) contains if a node has been published or unpublished (with `$node -> Status`), but I am not sure how to test this for each node and then add it to the body class.

[This question is similar](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39861/add-class-based-on-published-state), but the provided answer doesn't work.

2) Drupal 6
This [page explains](http://mydrupalblog.lhmdesign.com/classes-almost-everything-drupal-theme) how to do it for Drupal 6, but the code doesn't work for Drupal 7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in your theme's template.php:

```
function mytemplate_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $node = menu_get_object();
  if ($node && isset($node->nid)) {
    if ($node->status) {
      $vars['classes_array'][] = 'published';
    } else {
      $vars['classes_array'][] = 'unpublished';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This will work for EACH theme you add it to, so if you are using a backend theme you have to add it to the template.php file for that theme as well as your front-end theme.