# How to add a theme preprocess function for published state?

Tags: 8, theming, entities

I want to create a body class for the published state of a node. I found some suggestions below for Drupal 7, but this code is not working for my Drupal 8 theme.

[Add class based on published state](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39861/add-class-based-on-published-state)

How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fetch the node using `routeMatch` and add the class like this:

```
function THEME_NAME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $routeMatch = \Drupal::routeMatch();
  $node = $routeMatch->getParameter('node');
  if (isset($node) && $routeMatch->getRouteName() == 'entity.node.canonical') {
    if ($node->isPublished()) {
      $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'class-name-published';
    }
    else {
      $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'class-name-unpublished';
    } 
  }
}
```

This only adds the body class if you're on the `entity.node.canonical` route, to make sure that we always get a node object from the route parameter.

Comment: This is called on any route, so you might want to check either the route name or whether the route parameter is really a node object. There are routes in core which don't provide a node object by that parameter name.

Comment: See for example https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_mint/issues/2918947

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Added a check to see if we're on the correct route.

Comment: Works a treat. Thank you all.