# If content type with specific field that is not empty has specific taxonomy term attach library

Tags: 8, nodes, taxonomy-terms

I would like to attach a specific library using a taxonomy term to a content type with a specific field that is not empty. The following is not working:

```
function lehigh_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
// Via taxonomy term: If the landing page is a node and has taxonomy 
via a field named field_taxonomy
$current_route = \Drupal::routeMatch();
$node = $current_route->getParameter('node');
$target_taxonomy_id = 123;
   if ($node->getType() === 'standard_content_page') && $node->hasField('field_section') && !$node->get('field_section')->isEmpty()) {
     if ($node->get('field_section')->referencedEntities()[0]->id() == $target_taxonomy_id) {
     $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'lehigh/financialaid';
}
}
}
```

Comment: Well you need to learn to debug. Basically figure out what "if statement" is failing to pass.

Comment: Check the route name, otherwise you get an error when you use getType() on a route parameter which doesn't exist or is of the wrong type. See for example https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/285224/47547

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! So far, you stated facts, but you didn't ask any explicit question. If the implicit question is _Why doesn't my code work?_ that is a too broad question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following , and don't forget to clear the cache

```
function lehigh_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    $current_route = \Drupal::routeMatch();
    $node = $current_route->getParameter('node');
    $target_taxonomy_id = 123;
    if (isset($node) && $node->getType() == 'standard_content_page' 
        && $node->hasField('field_section') 
        && !$node->get('field_section')->isEmpty()) {
        if ($node->get('field_section')->referencedEntities()[0]->id() == $target_taxonomy_id) {
            $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'lehigh/financialaid';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There isn't the need of using all that code to get the node object, since that is already available in `$variables['node']`, if the page is a node page.

Comment: The `isset($node)` is good, because we're in `preprocess_page`: Not every page is a node and a non-node-page would crash on `$node->getType()`. But even some node routes (e.g. preview) don't do parameter upcasting, so better use `$node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface` instead

Comment: @Hudri I'm agree with you. did this solution work for you?

Comment: @YusefMohamadi I'm not the questioner, but I had wasted some hours due `(int) $current_route->getParameter('node')` ;-)

Comment: @Hudri, sorry I miss read. hundri, hunter :)

Comment: @YusefMohamadi Worked great - thanks so much!

Comment: @Hunter you're welcome. don't forget to mark as answer ;)